# How do I pass a value to a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have this code that changes the value of a variable called "factor" based upon a dropdown list selection:

```
sel.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
      var days = parseInt(evt.target.options[evt.target.selectedIndex].value);
      var factor = 0;
       switch (days) {
        case 3: case 4: var factor = 1.5; break;
        case 5: case 6: var factor = 1.4; break;
        case 7: case 8: case 9: var factor = 1.3; break;
        case 10: case 11: case 12: case 13: case 14: var factor = 1.2; break;
        case 15: default: var factor = 1.0;
      }
```

Then, I have this function that is supposed to use the variable called "factor" in a calculation based upon another (different) dropdown list selection:

```
psel.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {});
     function calculate (pfactor){
     var nopages = document.getElementById("pages");
     var priceOutput = document.getElementById("nopagesOutput");
     var pfactor = document.getElementById("factorOutput");
     priceOutput.innerHTML = nopages.value;

     var total = nopages.value * 10 * factor;
     document.getElementById("savings").innerHTML = `$ ${total}`;
```

I keep getting NaN as the result. How do I use the value in the variable called "factor" in the calculate(); function?

Comment: I'm trying to learn by doing this exercise. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: 1) You don't need to declare `var factor` on every option under switch-case. 
2) By declaring var inside of the eventHandler function, it exits scope when the function ends.  
3) In your addEventLIstener for `psel`, you're just adding an empty function.  The `calculate` function is independent.  Also, you declare `pfactor` as a parameter but then override it be declaring `var pfactor`
4) `var` is still allowed for legacy reasons, but has generally fallen out of favor for `let`, which scopes slightly differently.

Comment: That's a lot of good information. I wonder if I should clean up the code and resubmit the question. Javascript is definitely not my strong suit. Thank you very much. I'm not sure why, but before I added the psel handler, I wasn't getting any output from the calculate function when I selected from the dropdown list.

Comment: There's too many elements with either text or value in the calculation, I need HTML unless I just write the HTML the way it should be if you prefer the code to be optimal.

Comment: Thanks for your input. We're still working on it. I've come to a partial solution but am still experiencing a couple of end-user anomolies. I'll revisit it again later this week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The factor variable is declared local to the sel change event, so is not visible in the psel event.  You need to declare the factor variable outside of the event methods, or save to a hidden input type in sel, and get it from hidden input in psel.  Plus you just need the one var declaration, in the switch you don't need the var keyword, since factor has already been declared (var factor = 0)

In html

```
<input type="hidden id ="factor"/>
```

at bottom of sel

```
document.getElementById("factor").value = factor;
```

In psel

```
var factor = document.getElementById("factor").value
```

or just declare

```
var factor = 0
```

outside of the events (depending how your code is structured)

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much. I'm going to clean up the code and show what I've got with the resultant anomalies I've found later this week.

Answer (score 1):

Since there there was no HTML posted, the example has an optimal layout which includes:

- `<form>` - always wrap everything in a `<form>` if there is more than one form control
- `<input type='range'>` for the `days`
- 2 `<output>` - one to display number of `days` and one to display `saved`
- `<input type='number'>` for `price`

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Reference the <form>
const form = document.forms[0];
// Initialize output.view
form.elements.view.value = '3';
// Bind the <form> to the "input" event
form.addEventListener("input", function (evt) {
  // Reference all form controls
  const IO = this.elements;
  let factor; // Declare factor
  let price = +IO.price.value // Get price as a number
  let days = +IO.days.value; // Get days as a number
  IO.view.value = days; // Display number of days
  switch(days) {
    case 3: case 4: factor = 1.5; break;
    case 5: case 6: factor = 1.4; break;
    case 7: case 8: case 9: factor = 1.3; break;
    case 10: case 11: case 12: case 13: case 14: factor = 1.2; break;
    case 15: default: factor = 1.0;
  }
  // Call calculate - pass 2 numbers and a HTMLCollection
  calculate(factor, price, IO);
});

function calculate(factor, price, IO) {
  // Calculate parameters into a string with 2 decimals
  const total = (factor * price * 10).toFixed(2);
  // Display calculation
  IO.saved.value = '$'+total;
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

input {
  font: inherit;
}

#days {
  vertical-align: sub;
}

#price {
  width:9ch; 
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Factor:&nbsp;
    <input id='days' type='range' min='3' max='15' step='1' value='3'>
    &nbsp;<output id='view' value='3'></output> Days
  </label>
  <label>Price:&nbsp;
    <input id='price' type='number' min='.01' step='any' value='.01'>
  </label>
  <label>Savings:&nbsp;
    <output id='saved'></output>
  </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move `factor` variable to the outer scope that will share among functions

```
var factor = 0; //move `factor` from the function scope to the global scope

sel.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
      var days = parseInt(evt.target.options[evt.target.selectedIndex].value);
      //var factor = 0; //remove this
       switch (days) {
        case 3: case 4: var factor = 1.5; break;
        case 5: case 6: var factor = 1.4; break;
        case 7: case 8: case 9: var factor = 1.3; break;
        case 10: case 11: case 12: case 13: case 14: var factor = 1.2; break;
        case 15: default: var factor = 1.0;
      }
```

Now `factor` is visible in `calculate`, but you have another problem with your calculation is `nopages.value`. That value is possibly a string which cannot proceed number operations, so you need to convert it to a number by `Number(nopages.value)`

```
     function calculate (pfactor){
     var nopages = document.getElementById("pages");
     var priceOutput = document.getElementById("nopagesOutput");
     var pfactor = document.getElementById("factorOutput");
     priceOutput.innerHTML = nopages.value;

     var total = Number(nopages.value) * 10 * factor;
     document.getElementById("savings").innerHTML = `$ ${total}`;
```

Comment: Thank you. That resolved the NaN issue, but it keeps setting the variable called factor to zero outside the switch case code.

Comment: @somearabguy hmm `factor` is only set once after page reloading, could you share the code how you've constructed `factor` variable with other functions?

Comment: Yes. I'll get back to it later this week once I clean up the code. Thanks again.

Comment: sure, let me know if you still face any issue, @somearabguy